# I keep losing my stuff!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft and I'm not sure how to save my items/stuff when I die. I always lose my house and I found out I have to commit suicide to go back to my home. But then I can't find my items. This is always a problem for me! Please tell me the command for saving my items and for my house. My compass always points to the place where I spawn I don't understand I sleep at my house and I don't spawn there, is my compass broken?

Answer (score 7):

If cheats are enabled for your world, you can use `/gamerule keepInventory true` to keep your inventory on death.

If cheats are not enabled, you can temporarily open your world to LAN to enable cheats and change that gamerule.

Answer (score 4):

In Vanilla (Plain, un-modded, without [cheats enabled](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/161336/49600)) Minecraft there is no command to save your items.

When you die you drop everything that you are carrying at the time of death. The items stay on the ground for about 5 minutes, or if the chunk has been unloaded forever.

To set your spawn you need to sleep in a bed. Generally it's a good idea to wait a few seconds before getting out.

There are a couple conditions you may need to follow to have it set your spawn correctly:

- The bed is not touching walls.
- There is only regular blocks surrounding the bed. No glowstone, half-steps, glass, etc.
- There is enough space above, and around the bed to spawn.

> If a player's bed is destroyed or the bed is surrounded by solid blocks and the player dies when the player had set his spawnpoint there, a message is displayed saying Your home bed was missing or obstructed, and the player will respawn at the original spawn point. With this in mind, the player should know how to navigate to their base with the bed from the original spawn point, or keep their base near the original spawn point.

Above from [Minecraft Wiki: Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Behavior).

Comment: "The bed is not touching walls." - how sure are you about that? I've had beds in some quite enclosed spaces and re-spawned fine.

Comment: It is also worth noting that a compass will always point to the spawn point of the map, not your 'set-spawn' where your bed is.

Comment: @shanodin It's something I mention you 'may' need to follow. If it works beside a wall that's good. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Ender That's good to know, I didn't realise that. Thanks.

Comment: @shanodin That requirement is if the wall is on the outside of the structure since it may say "cannot sleep when there's monsters nearby" or similar message.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's three other ways to get to your home without suicide.

1: Use A Map, if your not going THAT far.

2: Use cobblestone or some other thing not related to dirt and make a pathway wherever you go.

3: Screenshot your house's X and Z. After your done exploring, just go that location.

I suggest these three because a Compass won't really help you that much.

Comment: A Compass will be of great use, if you know you can see it in statistics ;)